# Having negative waitGroup counter but why

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand go routines and played around with some code.
This one really makes me wonder. It's printing two or more values and then is erroring with

> panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

```
func processTheInt(i int, wg sync.WaitGroup){
    fmt.Println(i)
    wg.Done()

}


func main(){
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    for {
        theInt := rand.Intn(100)
        waitGroup.Add(1)
        go processTheInt(theInt, waitGroup)
    }

}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Before executing the go func processTheInt I'm increasing the counter. The function executes and decreasing it after printing. Is it because the printing takes longer than kicking off the function?

Comment: Read the do of syc.WaitGroup. You must not pass it around. Run `go vet`.

Comment: See [panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter with multiple requests to the same Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60438641/panic-sync-negative-waitgroup-counter-with-multiple-requests-to-the-same-endpo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to waitGroup variable

```
func processTheInt(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    fmt.Println(i)
    wg.Done()

}

func main(){
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    for {
        theInt := rand.Intn(100)
        waitGroup.Add(1)
        go processTheInt(theInt, &waitGroup)
    }

}
```

Otherwise it will copy the struct on every for iteration.

[`Read this to know the difference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872739/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-a-struct-and-pointer-of-the-struct-are-t)